# drawing unsual shapes using scss or css

Tags: html, user-interface, sass

I want to draw the below ripple using css.

[image]

The closest I darw was something like this.

[image]

```
display: block;
width: 126px;
height: 180px;
background-color: rgba(99, 83, 196, 0.38);
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to draw a half ripple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just two concentric circles that are masked by the rounded rectangle. You can achieve this with a circular gradient background:

```css
#out {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

#in {
  background: #fff;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 180px 10px, rgba(146,136,193,1) 30px, rgba(183,178,214,1) 30.5px, rgba(183,178,214,1) 50px, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50.5px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #6456BD;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div id="in">
    Usage<br>balances
  </div>
</div>
```